# Python : how to easily extract/store the various values of a json

Tags: python, json

I have the following sort of `JSON` file (way bigger but here is just a sample one), where the key element I have to retrieve is`"product_id"` belonging to `"list2"` (which based on tests, seems to be an array of a certain number of elements/items (don't know if the word "items" suits well):

```
{
"category": "game",
"list2":
        {
        "usage_rank": 1,
        "product_id": 203446,
        "product_name": "Ninja",
        },
        {
        "usage_rank": 6,
        "product_id": 564446,
        "product_name": "Samourai",
        },
"granularity": "monthly",
"segment": "all_users",
}
```

Basically I need to extract all the `"product_id"`, in order to make a second `API` call which would have this id info part of the URL.

I've tried various things, including with the loop the use of the method "get", and also to try to store the Json results into a ndarray ?

Is it what's necessary for sure to then efficiently re-use the information ?
I'm pretty confused between list, dictionary..

I have regular syntax errors (it seems I can't read properly the index), or when I don't have syntax errors  any more it seems that my loop only stores the first `"product_id"`, it doesn't then go to the second one.

At the end of the day, when I try a loop, I also have a syntax error for that :

```
json_data = json.loads(response.text)
i=0
print(i)
type(i)
for i in json_data["list"][i]["product_id"]:
    checkID=json_data["list"][i]["product_id"]
    print(checkID)
    i=i+1
```

I get :

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

But maybe there is a easier way to properly extract and save the `"product_id"` information ?

Comment: I see that there is no list key but list2

Comment: @eyllanesc as OP said: "[...] I have the following sort of JSON file (way bigger but here is just a sample one) [...]"

Comment: @dot.Py The keys are of the form `listX`, where X is number?

Comment: OP, please post the whole JSON data. The data you posted isn't a valid JSON, as verified at [JsonLint](http://jsonlint.com/).

Answer (score 0):

If you have properly formatted json:

```
{
"category": "game",
"list2":[
        {
        "usage_rank": 1,
        "product_id": 203446,
        "product_name": "Ninja"
        },
        {
        "usage_rank": 6,
        "product_id": 564446,
        "product_name": "Samourai"
        }],
"granularity": "monthly",
"segment": "all_users",
}
```

then following should work fine in grabbing `product_id`s from list2:

```
i = 2
for each in json_data['list'+str(i)]:
    print each['product_id']
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, make sure your JSON is correct, because in your example were missing the square brackets in your (I suppose) object's array.

Note: you may or may not use the `enumerate` function. It's up to you :)

Here is how you should iterate with the objects:

```
json_data = {
    "category": "game",
    "list2":[{
                "usage_rank": 1,
                "product_id": 203446,
                "product_name": "Ninja",
            },
            {
                "usage_rank": 6,
                "product_id": 564446,
                "product_name": "Samourai",
            }],
    "granularity": "monthly",
    "segment": "all_users",
}

for n, x in enumerate(json_data['list2'], 1):
    print(n, x['product_id'])
```

Comment: thanks a lot Thiago. Yes, had forgotten to mention the brackets. And also it is a true "list", don't know why it was written "list2". Actually, I have rows which are empty, would you know how to avoid to make the loop sort of crash?

Comment: I didn't understand what you said @gRookie. Provide me an example and I'll help you out ok? Waiting for your reply

Answer (score 0):

When you fix your json data, and assuming `list2` is actually, a `list` of dicts, we can use the following code to access the `product_id` values.

**Code:**

```
s = '''{
"category": "game",
"list2":
        [{
        "usage_rank": 1,
        "product_id": 203446,
        "product_name": "Ninja"
        },
        {
        "usage_rank": 6,
        "product_id": 564446,
        "product_name": "Samourai"
        }],
"granularity": "monthly",
"segment": "all_users"
}'''

import json

data = json.loads(s)

print(data['list2'][0])
print(data['list2'][1])

print(data['list2'][0]['product_id'])
print(data['list2'][1]['product_id'])
```

**Output:**

```
{'product_name': 'Ninja', 'product_id': 203446, 'usage_rank': 1}
{'product_name': 'Samourai', 'product_id': 564446, 'usage_rank': 6}
203446
564446
```

---

**And using a loop structure:**

```
for product in data['list2']:
    print(product['product_id'])
```

**Output:**

```
203446
564446
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem (apart from your slightly malformatted json and the fact that the `list` attribute is actually missing inside of it) is that you have two variables `i`, the counter and the iterator in the list, you have to differentiate between them:

```
json_data = json.loads(response.text)
i1=0
print(i1)
type(i1)
for i2 in json_data["list"]:
# or:
# for i2 in range(len(son_data["list"])):
    checkID=json_data["list"][i1]["product_id"]
    # or:
    # checkID=i2["product_id"] # then you don't even need i1
    print(checkID)
    i1=i1+1
```